# Is it possible to have 100% branch coverage without 100% statement coverage?

Tags: testing, code-coverage

I am trying to think of examples where 100% branch coverage is reached but statement coverage is less than 100%.

So far I can't think of any way possible for this to happen. Is there something obvious I am missing or am I over thinking this simple problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.
Consult [ISTQB Foundation Level Syllabus](https://www.istqb.org/downloads/send/2-foundation-level-documents/3-foundation-level-syllabus-2011.html4) page 42
Section 4.4.2 clearly states that decision (branch) coverage is stronger than statement coverage; 100% decision coverage implies 100% statement coverage, but not other way around.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.
100% branch coverage subsumes 100% statement coverage.